# What is wrong in this block of code, creates 34 memory leaks on this block?

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks

[image][image]I don't know what i'm doing wrong in this block, but while checking it through instruments>leaks it shows 34 leaks and sometimes less leaks on this block, what is wrong in it, please share your expert opinion with me to understand the reasons of leaks.

```
public func getInspectionAddressCoordinates(requestMessage: InspectionServiceRequestMessage) -> (ServiceResponseMessage){


    if Global.shared.isConnected {

        let params = [
            "address": requestMessage.inspectionAddress.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "+", options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch, range: nil)
        ]
        let networkRequestMessage = RequestNetworkMessage(requestType: RequestType.GET, contentType: ContentType.ContentTypeHTML, url: MAP_URL, params: params)

        let networkResponseMessage = BaseNetwork().performNetworkTask(requestMessage: networkRequestMessage)

        switch networkResponseMessage.statusCode {
        case .Success:

            if let data = networkResponseMessage.data as? NSData {

                do {
                    let jsonObject: AnyObject = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)

                    if let jsonDict = jsonObject as? [String: AnyObject] {
                        if let results = jsonDict["results"] as? [AnyObject] {
                            for dict in results {
                                if let geo = dict["geometry"] as? [String: AnyObject] {
                                    if let loc = geo["location"] as? [String: AnyObject] {
                                        if let lat = loc["lat"] as? Double {
                                            if let lon = loc["lng"] as? Double {
                                                print("\(lat), \(lon)")
                                                let msg = self.getSuccessResponseMessage("Inspection Status Updated")
                                                msg.data = ["lat":lat, "lon": lon]
                                                return msg
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
            } catch _ {
                    return self.getErrorResponseMessage("Unable to parse")
            }
            return self.getErrorResponseMessage("Unable to parse")

            }
            else {
                return self.getErrorResponseMessage("Unable to parse")
            }
        case .Failure:
            return self.getErrorResponseMessage("Network error in inspection status update request")
        case .Timeout:
            return self.getTimeoutErrorResponseMessage("Inspection status update request has been timed out")
        }
    }
    else  {
        return self.getErrorResponseMessage(ERROR_NO_NETWORK)
    }
}
```

Comment: What leak you'r talking about, still not getting you. Pls specify your requirement your approach and your issue differently so that we can understand properly and explain solution more precisely

Comment: i've added the picture of instruments, and i was talking about memory leaks remember.. :)

Comment: Click on Ⓔ button to get the exact stack trace and cause of the each memory leak. You should be able to get the exact line. If you already did that, try keeping this block inside @autoreleasepool block once and check whether it got resolved. Otherwise, let me know